# TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' : DjangoRestframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting an error, `save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` .

I have no idea where I made mistake, it would be great if anybody could figure out the mistake, they would be much appreciated.

serializers.py

```
           UserOtherInfo_obj = User(
                device_token    =   device_token,
                device_type     =   device_type,
                phone_number    =   phone_number,
                country_code    =   country_code,
                login_type      =   login_type
            )    
            
            UserOtherInfo_temp  =  User.save()
            
            temp_user1 = User.objects.filter(user=temp_user)
            print('temp_user1',temp_user1)
            UserOtherObj = temp_user1.first()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
UserOtherInfo_temp  =  UserOtherInfo_obj.save()
```

Before, you directly were calling *save* on `User` model, but you can *save* only the *instance* of `User` model, which you instantiated just a line above i.e:

```
UserOtherInfo_obj = User(
                device_token    =   device_token,
                device_type     =   device_type,
                phone_number    =   phone_number,
                country_code    =   country_code,
                login_type      =   login_type
            )
```

Here, `UserOtherInfo_obj` is instance of `User` model.